# Qt 4.8.7 widget->move() not working on ARM linux

Tags: linux, qt, embedded-linux

I have the following code:

```
QWidget* widget = ...
...
widget->move(x, y);
assert(widget->pos().x() == x);
assert(widget->pos().y() == y);
```

This assert holds on both Windows and Linux, but fails on embedded linux.
Qt was built from source on all operating systems.

Is there any known work around for this issue?

Comment: It maybe not even correct to verify right away but after event loop worked.

Comment: @AlexanderV I reached to this because the widgets were all grouped on top left corner. Not sure why...